# Sports commentators' English

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage

Football commentators are not renowned for their erudition, but one particular usage I am finding wearisome. I am not writing this by way of complaint as I know that is not the purpose of the site. But I would be interested to know whether other people regard this as a correct use of English.

When an attacking player falls over in the penalty area one of three things may have happened:

1) He accidentally fell over.
2) He was fouled by a defender.
3 He 'dived', meaning he fell down deliberately in order to make the referee think he had been fouled and award a penalty kick (and possibly a red card to the defender).

Now in the inevitable cut and thrust of argument that goes on among the pundits following such an incident, they will say variously 'I don't think it was a penalty', 'It was definitely a penalty', 'It is a difficult decision, the ref is in no position to say whether it's a penalty or not'.

What they actually mean is 'I don't know if it was cause for a penalty' or 'a penalty should have been given'. In no literal sense was such an incident 'a penalty'. A penalty is potentially that which follows.

Are others satisfied that the Gary Linekers, and Alan Shearers of this world get it (the English) right when they say 'It was a penalty'.

The same sort of thing applies to free-kicks, corners and throw-ins.

Comment: Technically it might be incorrect, but it doesn't bother me too much. It gets the meaning across, which is the point of language. But I'm curious why they don't just say "foul". That's what an American basketball commentator would say ("that was a foul", "Kareem fouled Larry", etc).

Comment: I'm going to second what @MikeBaranczak says.  It's not correct, but it's accepted as standard.

Comment: I’d say this is a subtype of synecdoche, really. Similar expressions do exist—I can easily imagine someone seeing a car flash by at twice the speed limit, and then saying, “Now that’s definitely a lost permit!”. It isn’t, of course; but if the police catch up with the driver, a lost permit is likely to be the outcome. Or when a commentator describes a gymnastics performance as a ‘sure 10’. I’d say it’s quite a reasonable and common extension, all in all.

Comment: In this context "penalty" is just an abbreviation of "penalty kick".

Answer (score 3):

This is a common kind of metonymy (effect for cause). Metonymy is where the literal thing is replaced by something related to it (part for whole, cause for effect, product for process, tool for industry, and so on).

There is the expectation that the listener will understand the literal meaning ("undo" the metonymy) and it is used for overlying reasons of emphasis, style, brevity, focus, etc.

Metonymy has been common in rhetoric and everyday speech throughout history.

Examples of metonymy generally include "talk to the press", "released by Hollywood", "hired a hundred hands". Effect-for-cause examples include "he is an accident waiting to happen", "He was a heartthrob" or "I am the resurrection and the life".

Last two examples, and further from:
http://www.wls.wels.net/sites/default/files/psi/nt3001/Lesson01MetonymyOfEffectForCause.pdf

Comment: +1 for recognizing metonymy in the wild. In this case I think it would be effect for cause, however, although those two items do represent the things being switched.

Comment: You're right, effect for cause, not cause for effect! I'll edit my answer.

Comment: But saying 'I don't think it was a penalty' is potentially ambiguous, and hence not quite the same as the examples you quote. It could mean that the referee did not actually award a penalty. Much better to say 'I don't think it merited a penalty'.